# Why gf is not working with variable?

Tags: variables, cursor, environment-variables

If there is no variable in path, gf can open the file.
Added `sfname+={,}` to .vimrc to support ${VARIABLE}.
`:!echo ${VAR}/test/file` can correctly print full path with ${VAR} expanded.
But if run 'gf' on it, it gives error: `E447: Can't find file "${VAR}/test/file" in path`
How to fix this?

Comment: According to `:h expand-env` and `:h gf`, environmental variables are expanded in the form `$HOME`. Can you use this form instead of `${HOME}`? Otherwise you will need to probably use `'includeexpr'` and a substitution (`substitute('${HOME}/test/file', '\${\([^}]*\)}', '\=expand("$".submatch(1))', 'g')`)

Comment: @PeterRincker want to turn that into a real answer?

Comment: @PeterRincker, now ${HOME} is working, but other variable name as ${ROOT} is still not working.

Comment: @PeterRincker, found the reason, need to define variable as `let $ROOT = '/full/path'`. Can't define it as `let $ROOT = '~/path'`. After $ROOT is defined and the expanded path is valid, I can `gf` goto the file.